# NHibernate mapping files: DOCTYPE still not supported?

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate-mapping

In Java-Hibernate (version 4.2) I used a feature to conveniently include other XML documents in another XML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"[
    <!ENTITY authorizables SYSTEM  "classpath://authorizables.xml">
]>
...
<any name="Authorizable" meta-type="string" id-type="long">
    &authorizables; <!-- application specifc meta-value definitions for Authorizables with long-ID -->
    ...
</any>
```

and authorizables.xml (residing in a different package and jar-file) contains the concrete classes

```
<meta-value value="Spiel" class="otherpackage.class1"/>
<meta-value value="Team" class="otherpackage.class1"/>
```

In NHibernate 5.1 (for C#) I tried the same mapping approach, but get exception

```
NHibernate.MappingException
+ InnerException    {"DTD is prohibited in this XML document ... System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
```

From this (quite old) post [Using Doctype in Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224861/using-doctype-in-nhibernate) I understnd that
the DOCTYPE feature was dropped (some years ago) from NHibernate although it is still documented in the NHibernate Reference Documentation
Version: 5.1, chapter 8.1.6.

I also could not find a documented hibernate config property to allow DOCTYPE processing.

Is DOCTYPE still not supported ?
(Then I would have to try a different mapping approch).

Comment: DOCTYPE cannot be the first line of the XML file in Net Library.  Normally the xml ident line will be the first line.

Comment: Yes I know, I did show only relevant parts of my mapping files

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not find a solution with DOCTYPE on the net, I choose a different mapping approach:

- made the class of my common assembly an `abstract` "base class"
- declared this class also `abstract="true"` in the mapping file and
  removed the `<any`... section
- derived a class from the base class in my business model assembly
- mapped the latter as `<union-subclass` ... with my existing database table and put the `<any`... section here with all the business model specific `<meta-value` ... definitions

I also had to replace `new` "base class" in my code with `new` "derived class", but this is acceptable, since all these places are in my business model assembly.